# BC30554: 'xxxxDBDataContext' is ambiguous

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, ambiguous

I'm working on a VB.net project in VS 2012 and I'm getting the below error message.

Error Details 
C:\xxx\xxxApp\xxxApplication.aspx(51): error BC30554: 'xxxxDBDataContext' is ambiguous.

Error Source 
System.Web

Here is the screenshot of the source code
[image: Code behind]
[image: utility class]

Comment: aparantely the image did not show. 
below are the link.. 

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bwl0qZszHlDleXl4STVTVVYxVTQ&usp=sharing

Comment: The images didn't show because what you've put in there are the sharing links that will allow other people to edit the images in their own google drive accounts.  You might want to edit that.

Answer (score 0):

The error "'<ClassName>' is ambiguous" is usually given when the compiler encounters two identical classes (or a class and a namespace, etc.) that are either in the same namespace, or have both been imported into your environment.  So, for example, if you had `System.Data.DataTable` and `MyNamespace.DataTable` and had imported both of them into your environment:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports MyNamespace
```

If after this you just referenced:

```
Dim dt As DataTable
```

Then the compiler will tell you `'DataTable' is ambiguous` because it doesn't know which one you're referring to.  You need to qualify the name with either:

```
Dim dt As System.Data.DataTable
```

or

```
Dim dt As MyNameSpace.DataTable
```